# OpenDKIM - How can I set these signing options in the conf file

Tags: postfix, dkim, opendkim

I followed [this guide](http://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2011/08/installing-opendkim-rpm-via-yum-with-postfix-or-sendmail-for-rhel-centos-fedora/%20) for opendkim, and I wondering how to set the following options in the conf file:

- Signature expiration (x)
- creation time (t)
- standard headers to be validated (h=)
- body signature length (l=) to be auto determined and included in the signature

From what I have seen, these flags might be for the public key, but am not 100% sure, I would like to these via the opendkim.conf file if I can. Otherwise if I were to add these to my public key in plain text, would I need to somehow change my private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all set in your public dns txt record, as long as your k=, v=, and p= match the generated key you'll be fine.

The value of p= is used to validate the message, other options are just extra options and can be manipulated at your discretion.

http://dkim.org/specs/rfc4871-dkimbase.html#rfc.section.7.4

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I would be able to specify all of them when I set the dns record? okay, that make sense. I did not know if I somehow needed those options in my private key. Once I get my dns record hopefully up and running I will mark this as the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again, I was able to set most of the options in the conf file. Any idea how to set the body length in opendkim since they took that out in 2.4 and now I'm on 2.10.3?

Comment: I'm not sure, did you try the mailing list?

Comment: yeah, I tried it a few days ago. Nothing back so far